# SWT creating an on-top message dialog

Tags: java, swt

I'd like to create a SWT `MessageDialog`, e.g., a question, which is on top of all windows, at least initially.

My first idea was via `Shell`. I see that one can create a `Shell` with style `ON_TOP`. But with the `MessageDialog` methods, I just can set a parent shell.  How can I set that style for the window that `MessageDialog` opens?

Comment: The question body includes 'AWT' and it's also tagged as [tag:awt] yet both `MessageDialog` and the `Shell` API are part of **[tag:swt]**. Which is it? Please [edit] the question once that's figured out.

Comment: Have you tried creating a shell and set is as the dialog parent shell?

Comment: @tkotisis. I did. Result were differences between Linux and Windows. In particular, it opened a blank window on Linux, in addition to the question window.

Comment: Does a modal dialog fit your needs? If yes see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370452/display-parent-modal-dialog-with-swt

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass the `Dialog` class and call the `setShellStyle(int newShellStyle)` method:

```java
public class OnTopDialog extends MessageDialog {

    public OnTopDialog(Shell parentShell, String dialogTitle, Image dialogTitleImage, String dialogMessage, int dialogImageType, int defaultIndex, String[] dialogButtonLabels) {
        super(parentShell, dialogTitle, dialogTitleImage, dialogMessage, dialogImageType, defaultIndex, dialogButtonLabels);
        setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.ON_TOP);
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work because the open() method of MessageDialog creates a new MessageDialog object on which it operates, hence the new constructor is not used. Furthermore, open() eliminates all shell styles but the two mentioned in its JavaDoc. So, you have to reimplement everything

Comment: The open() method does not create a new dialog.
You are referring to the static open(...) method. Not sure why you need to use that.

Comment: Even so, all you need to reimplement is the open(...) method if you need a similar convenience method.